# view image on button click. qt

Tags: c++, image, qt, pixmap

I created a label in my main window and its size is set to 200x300px. now on a button click i need to view a image in it. here is the slot function of the button.

```
 void MainWindow::function1(){
QImage img;
img.loadFromData("test.jpg");
img = img.scaled(200, 300, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
}
```

the problem is this compiles without errors, but not displaying the image. insted when the button is pressed it says `QImage::scaled: Image is a null image` in the IDE
im new in qt. I would be very thankful for any advice.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `QImage` is necessary if you are processing images outside of your GUI thread.  Also the `loadFromData()` function looks like it is used for passing in a large array of bytes, not the name of the file.

Here is how I would do it with a QPixmap.

```
QPixmap pix;

bool loaded = pix.load("test.jpg");

if(loaded == false)
{
    label->setText("Failed to load test.jpg from" + QDir::currentPath());
}
else
{
    pix = pix.scaled(200, 300, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
    label->setPixmap(pix);
}
```

You may also want to replace 200 and 300 with `label->width()` and `label->height()`.  Scaling a pixmap this way looks the best, but you can also just set the pixmap and then use `label->setScaledContents(true)`

Comment: thanks this worked. but when I replaced `img.load("test.jpg")` in my code it dont work. whats the mistake here.

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with it not finding the file, the format not being auto-detected correctly, or the dll for processing jpg's with QImage not being found.  When you get ready to deploy this, you may need to make sure you have in your exe's directory "/imageformats/qjpeg4.dll" copied from "QTDIR/plugins".

If you check the return values on your function calls, you can see if it failed to load or failed to scale, or if it is something else.  Sometimes Qt will put the error in the output at runtime, too.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

`img.loadFromData("test.jpg");`

use

`img.load("test.jpg");`

if you're loading from a QIODevice.